# Rewrite in the contiki source code “example-mesh.c” to send messages based on a timer value

Tags: c++

The example in Contiki " example-mesh.c " is designed to send a message every time the button is pressed but I want this example to send data periodically every 5 seconds for example instead of pressing on button so I need to rewrite the example "example-mesh.c"  to send messages based on a timer value. here is the code with but  I run the simulation in the mote output window only 3 messages are sent while the rest is " packet timedout " how can I solve that problem :

```html
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/rime.h"
#include "net/rime/mesh.h"

#include "contiki-conf.h"
#include "sys/etimer.h"
#include "sys/process.h"
#include "sys/ctimer.h"


#include "dev/leds.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MESSAGE "Hello"

static struct mesh_conn mesh;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(example_mesh_process, "Mesh example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&example_mesh_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
sent(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet sent\n");
}

static void
timedout(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
     
  printf("packet timedout\n");
}

static void
recv(struct mesh_conn *c, const rimeaddr_t *from, uint8_t hops)
{
  printf("Data received from %d.%d: %.*s (%d)\n",
  from->u8[0], from->u8[1],
  packetbuf_datalen(), (char *)packetbuf_dataptr(), packetbuf_datalen());

  packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
  mesh_send(&mesh, from);
}

const static struct mesh_callbacks callbacks = {recv, sent, timedout};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(example_mesh_process, ev, data)
{

   static struct etimer et;

  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(mesh_close(&mesh);)

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  mesh_open(&mesh, 132, &callbacks);

 etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND +50);


  while(1) {
   rimeaddr_t addr;

 PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et)); 
 
    /* Send a message to node number 1. */
    
    packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
    addr.u8[0] = 1;
    addr.u8[1] = 0;
    mesh_send(&mesh, &addr);
}
  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag C?

Comment: My code is C++  @Neil Kirk

Comment: But the file is "example-mesh.c" not "example-mesh.cpp"

Comment: yes this file is "example-mesh.c"

Comment: So it's not C++ code it's C code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying in the contiki source code "example-mesh.c" to send messages based on a timer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044703/modifying-in-the-contiki-source-code-example-mesh-c-to-send-messages-based-on)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a couple of years old by now but here is how I would do it. I used the examples/rime/example-mesh.c program and modified it to trigger off of a timer expiration instead of a button push. I loaded this on a TelosB (Sky mote) and it worked. And yes, Contiki is written in C not C++.

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/rime/rime.h"
#include "net/rime/mesh.h"
#include "sys/etimer.h"

#include "dev/button-sensor.h"

#include "dev/leds.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE "Hello"

static struct mesh_conn mesh;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(example_mesh_process, "Mesh example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&example_mesh_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
sent(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet sent\n");
}

static void
timedout(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet timedout\n");
}

static void
recv(struct mesh_conn *c, const linkaddr_t *from, uint8_t hops)
{
  printf("Data received from %d.%d: %.*s (%d)\n",
     from->u8[0], from->u8[1],
     packetbuf_datalen(), (char *)packetbuf_dataptr(), packetbuf_datalen());

  packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
  mesh_send(&mesh, from);
}

const static struct mesh_callbacks callbacks = {recv, sent, timedout};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(example_mesh_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(mesh_close(&mesh);)
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  mesh_open(&mesh, 132, &callbacks);

  //SENSORS_ACTIVATE(button_sensor);


  static struct etimer et;



  while(1) {
    linkaddr_t addr;

    /* Wait for button click before sending the first message. */
    //PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev == sensors_event && data == &button_sensor);

    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 5);

    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

    printf("Timer Expired!\n\r");

    /* Send a message to node number 1. */

    packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
    addr.u8[0] = 1;
    addr.u8[1] = 0;
    mesh_send(&mesh, &addr);
  }
  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```